# Interfaces in a linux character driver

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver

Can anyone explain the interfaces involved with a linux char driver and the corresponding component(s) providing it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need the header file [`linux/fs.h`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/fs.h), where functions for the file system are declared. This is needed because a character driver manages the access to a character device which is typically represented as a file in `/dev`.

If you run `ls -l` in `/dev` you see some lines like this:

```
crw-rw----.  1 root lp          6,   0 14. Feb 18:23 lp0
crw-rw----.  1 root lp          6,   1 14. Feb 18:23 lp1
crw-rw----.  1 root lp          6,   2 14. Feb 18:23 lp2 
crw-rw----.  1 root lp          6,   3 14. Feb 18:23 lp3
crw-rw-rw-.  1 root tty         5,   0 15. Feb 10:57 tty
crw--w----.  1 root tty         4,   0 14. Feb 18:23 tty0
```

The `c` at the beginning of a line indicates character device files. These are nodes in the file system with which you can communicate with the device through a driver. The two numbers before the date indicate which driver is used for that device. For instance, `lp0` has the numbers `6` and `0`. The first number is called major and the second minor. The major number is used by the kernel to chose the right driver for this device. In `/proc/devices` you find the kernel module names, the actual driver, for this numbers. The second number is only use by the driver so that it is possible to manage more than one device with one driver. For instance, `lp0-3` above use all the driver with the major number `6`.

The old and simple way to register your driver and produce an entry in `/dev/devices` is to call the following function.

```
int register_chrdev(unsigned int major, const char *name,
                       const struct file_operations *fops)
```

`major` is the major number of your driver, `name` is the name which will appear in `/dev/devices` and `fops` is a pointer to a jump table with all the functions of your driver. This is realised with the struct `file_operations`. You have to look for this struct in the `fe.h` of your kernel to know the supported functions. Than you define this struct in your driver and put in the function names of your driver and NULL for functions your driver does not support. For the NULL entries some defaults are used then. More comfortable is it to use the [C tagged structure initialization syntax](https://linuxprograms.wordpress.com/2008/03/07/c-structure-initialization-advanced/).The most important functions are `lseek`, `read` and `write`. There the device is represented by a `file` struct also defined in `linux/fs.h`.

In newer code one uses the `cdev` struct in [`linux/cdev.h`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/cdev.h) instead of the above function.
For this way and more details of driver programming I recommend this: http://www.oreilly.com/openbook/linuxdrive3/book/ch03.pdf.

If you have your compiled driver, you can load it with `insmod` into the kernel. If you want to use `modprobe` you have look up how it is configured on your system because it differs. To get a node in `/dev` for the device one uses `mknod`. For a character device with major number `10` and minor number `0` it looks like this:

```
mknod /dev/my_device c 10 0
```